# Type and focus out event in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a `blur()` event to handle focus out event on a text field. The code looks like this.

```
$("input[type=text]").blur(function (event) {
    if(this.value){
        //do something
    }
    event.originalEvent.handled = true;
});
```

I have a situation where a text-field is automatically getting focus with the text from previous page.

To give an example, in `flipkart.com`, type some text in the search field and click search. My `event handler` must execute for focus out event. (It is happening correctly).

In the next page, the text entered is prepopulated in the text-field and focus is also on it. So in this page, if I do some action, the text-field will lose focus and the same event gets called again. I don't need this to happen.

Is there a way to avoid this? By combining two event handlers? Please help.

Comment: you can you **$("#xyz").focusout()**

Comment: Try `$(':text').on('focus blur', function() ...`

Comment: first thing is use text box id instead of $("input[type=text]"). Second thing is   you can set a focus on other element instead of that particular control using SetFocus method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code so that the function is only bound to the element **after** a user explicitly interacts with the element like so:

```js
$("input[type=text]").on('keyup keypress change click', function() {
  $("input[type=text]").blur(function(event) {
    if (this.value) {
      //do something
      alert('blur was called after interacting with element');
    }
    event.originalEvent.handled = true;
  });
});
$('#test').focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test" value="some value">
```

Comment: What if the page itself is changed? In case of flipkart, in home page if I type search text, in the results page, the same field will have the same text and the focus is on it by default.

Comment: @NaveenBharadwaj Yep, but none of that will trigger the `$("input[type=text]").on('keyup keypress change click'` ....unless you are setting the value to the box after the page loads with jQuery like `$(selector).val('valueFromPreviousPage');` which  I doubt you'd be doing

Comment: I just needed change event in that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You know the text value from previous page, just compare it with current text value, if both same then don't do any action. See below code

```
$(function(){
   var prevTextValue = "read your previous text value here";
   $("input[type=text]").blur(function (event) {
      //check if value is not empty and not equal to previous value
      if(this.value!="" && this.value != prevTextValue){
        //do something
      }
      event.originalEvent.handled = true;
   });
});
```

Comment: what if i want to enter the search string as previous page?

Comment: why you want to search it again when you got search result already?

Comment: What if the search was something akin to the newest questions on SO with a jQuery tag. Just playing devils advocate here, but that might be a case where you would want to allow re-searching with the same parameter